# BaseGameUtils cannot resolve symbol android in: "com.google.android.gms.games.Games"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm trying to make an app with G+ and Google play services.

But I can't from the beginning.

I try to import the project BaseGameUtils, and build the app (sync with Gradle) and run it.

Surprisingly it runs! and works, but when I go into the code, my imports are not found.(cannot resolve symbol)

This leads me to think that my Gradle is well configured but I am missing something (library, dependency, module) in the app, because Android Studio complains about it.

I have the latest Android Studio 0.8.9, and my SDK is updated with all the needed installs.

Can someone put a "how to" import the BaseGameUtils project/library step by step for latest Android Studio and what else is needed?

Also, my Gradle is configured so the app builds with app support v4, but as before, it cannot be resolved.
How do I add it? I already have it in Project Structure > Modules > app > Dependencies > support-v4 as library dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it almost. It's very important to put your to the latest version (build.gradle --> compileSdkVersion 21). The same with the dependencies (    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils'),    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+' and the latest version of Google PLay Services compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'. Of course you should update your SDK files first (install API21+Tools)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's a bug when importing a project with BaseGameUtils dependency from eclipse to Android Studio. This can be solved by commenting out this import as it is no longer required:

//import com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.r;